# Trying to delete parent node based on innerHTML - Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, hide

I need to remove the option to delete attachments. The function I tried to do this with gave me this error: **Cannot read property 'nodeValue' of undefined**

[image]

I tired doing this:

```
function hideDelete (){
    $("a").filter(function () { return $.trim(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue) === "Delete"; }).closest("td").hide();                  
}
```

HTML:

```
<td class="ms-propertysheet"><img alt="Delete" src="/_layouts/images/rect.gif">&nbsp;<a tabindex="1" href="javascript:RemoveAttachmentFromServer('{2088EB08-E376-4637-A6F9-35675AF46E35}',1)">Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: Maybe try: `return this.childNodes[0] && $.trim(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue) === "Delete";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$('td a').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.text() == 'Delete'){
        $this.parent().html('');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5qprY/

Comment: In your snippet the td is always the direct parent.  Instead of attempting to hide an inline element you can either hide the contents of the element, or in this example, empty the contents.

Comment: Oh so here you're not hiding the cell but just replacing the contents inside <a><a/>?

Comment: It is replacing the entire contents of that cell.  You might want to use .html('&nbsp;') to avoid the cell collapsing.

Comment: @Daniel why don't you simply call `.hide()` on `.parent()` instead of `.html('')`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5qprY/2/  hiding the cell will cause the other cells to shift formatting.